# F# replacing variables with actual values results in endless loop (recursive function)

Tags: recursion, f#, infinite-loop

I recently started with F# and implemented a very basic recursive function that represents the Sieve of Eratosthenes. I came up with the following, working code:

```
static member internal SieveOfEratosthenesRecursive sequence accumulator =
    match sequence with
    | [] -> accumulator
    | head::tail -> let rest = tail |> List.filter(fun number -> number % head <> 0L)
                    let newAccumulator = head::accumulator
                    Prime.SieveOfEratosthenesRecursive rest newAccumulator
```

This function is not really memory efficient so I tried to eliminate the variables "rest" and "newAccumulator". I came up with the following code

```
static member internal SieveOfEratosthenesRecursive sequence accumulator =
    match sequence with
    | [] -> accumulator
    | head::tail -> tail    |> List.filter(fun number -> number % head <> 0L) 
                            |> Prime.SieveOfEratosthenesRecursive (head::accumulator)
```

As far as I understand the tutorials I've read Prime.SieveOfEratosthenesRecursive will be called with the filtered *tail* as first parameter and a list consisting of *head::accumulator* as second one. However when I try to run the code with the reduced variable usage, the program gets trappen in an infinite loop. Why is this happening and what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I understand the tutorials I've read Prime.SieveOfEratosthenesRecursive will be called with the filtered `tail` as first parameter and a list consisting of `head::accumulator` as second one.

You have this backwards.

In the first version, you're passing `rest` then `newAccumulator`; in the second version, you're effectively passing `newAccumulator` then `rest`. I.e., you've transposed the arguments.

`Prime.SieveOfEratosthenesRecursive (head::accumulator)` is a partial function application wherein you're applying `(head::accumulator)` as the first argument (`sequence`). This partial function application yields a unary function (expecting `accumulator`), to which you are passing (via `|>`) what is called `rest` in the first version of your code.

Changing `SieveOfEratosthenesRecursive`'s argument order is the easiest solution, but I would consider something like the following idiomatic as well:

```
static member internal SieveOfEratosthenesRecursive sequence accumulator =
    match sequence with
    | [] -> accumulator
    | head::tail ->
        tail
        |> List.filter(fun number -> number % head <> 0L) 
        |> Prime.SieveOfEratosthenesRecursive <| (head::accumulator)
```

or

```
static member internal SieveOfEratosthenesRecursive sequence accumulator =
    let inline flipzip a b = b, a
    match sequence with
    | [] -> accumulator
    | head::tail ->
        tail
        |> List.filter(fun number -> number % head <> 0L) 
        |> flipzip (head::accumulator)
        ||> Prime.SieveOfEratosthenesRecursive
```

---

FWIW, eliminating `rest` and `newAccumulator` as named variables here is not going to impact your memory usage in the slightest.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for pointing that out. The pipelined parameter will be passed in as last parameter

Answer (score 1):

The last call in your second function is equivalent to:

```
Prime.SieveOfEratosthenesRecursive newAccumulator rest
```

where you switch positions of two params. Since `newAccumulator` grows bigger after each recursive call, you will never reach the base case of empty list.

The rule of thumb is putting the most frequently changing parameter at last:

```
let rec sieve acc xs =
    match xs with
    | [] -> acc
    | x::xs' -> xs' |> List.filter (fun y -> y % x <> 0L) 
                    |> sieve (x::acc)
```

The above function could be shortened using `function` keyword:

```
let rec sieve acc = function
    | [] -> acc
    | x::xs' -> xs' |> List.filter (fun y -> y % x <> 0L) 
                    |> sieve (x::acc)
```

Using pipe (`|>`) operator only makes the function more readable, it doesn't affect memory usage at all.